# Removing white-spaces in a selected part of a text file

Tags: bash, sed

Following is a typical example of a text. I would like to remove the white spaces before the letter `S` from the second line to the seventh line.

```
$begin
  S   23.1394048  -10.8890421    0.2596120
  S   23.7763785   -9.4142178    0.2600115
  S   24.3203694   -7.9027092    0.2596413
  S   24.7669178   -6.3595161    0.2599540
  S   25.1173247   -4.7917893    0.2597617
  S   25.3678890   -3.2049607    0.2598870
  S   25.5189950   -1.6056392    0.2599152
$end

$input
    structre = ABC
    Condition1 = default
    Condition2 = default
    Condition3 = default
    Condition4 = default
    Condition5 = default
    Condition6 = default
$end
```

The white-spaces in other lines is intentional. I guess it can be done in `sed` editor. The final output should be as follow (without white spaces before the matching line, here " S "

```
$begin
S   23.1394048  -10.8890421    0.2596120
S   23.7763785   -9.4142178    0.2600115
S   24.3203694   -7.9027092    0.2596413
S   24.7669178   -6.3595161    0.2599540
S   25.1173247   -4.7917893    0.2597617
S   25.3678890   -3.2049607    0.2598870
S   25.5189950   -1.6056392    0.2599152
$end

    $input
    structre = ABC
    Condition1 = default
    Condition2 = default
    Condition3 = default
    Condition4 = default
    Condition5 = default
    Condition6 = default
    $end
```

How this can be done?

Comment: Is the indentation of the $input intentional here? It is not mentioned and it looks wrong.

Comment: Yes. The indentation of the $input is intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use sed:

```
▶ sed 's/^  S/S/' data.txt 
$begin
S   23.1394048  -10.8890421    0.2596120
S   23.7763785   -9.4142178    0.2600115
S   24.3203694   -7.9027092    0.2596413
S   24.7669178   -6.3595161    0.2599540
S   25.1173247   -4.7917893    0.2597617
S   25.3678890   -3.2049607    0.2598870
S   25.5189950   -1.6056392    0.2599152
$end

$input
    structre = ABC
    Condition1 = default
    Condition2 = default
    Condition3 = default
    Condition4 = default
    Condition5 = default
    Condition6 = default
$end
```